# Scale Y axis of matplotlib plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib

I want to scale Y axis so that I can see values, as code below plots cant see anything other than a thin black line. Changing plot height doesn't expand the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.random.random((4,10000))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,100)
#or swap line above with one below, still no change in plot height
#fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 100))
plt.matshow(data)
plt.show()
```

One way to do this is just repeat the values then plot result, but I would have thought it possible to just scale the height of the plot?

```
data_repeated = np.repeat(data, repeats=1000, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data=np.random.random((4, 10000))
plt.figure(figsize=(40, 10))
plt.matshow(data, fignum=1, aspect='auto')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Resized matshow figure]